# Is it possible to have a 2-in-1 USB device that is a Flash Drive and Power Bank?

Tags: usb, charging, drive

I spent over an hour with no luck looking for a device that would provide flash storage and provide charging power to another device at the same time.  I would think this would be possible as you can plug a phone into a computer and receive data as well as charging power simultaneously.  If a 2-in-1 device is possible, does it already exist for purchase?  Maybe it has a different name and I am searching with the wrong terminology.

Comment: Sorry, this site is for electronics design questions. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power banks typically are USB **hosts** so they can negotiate about voltage and current requirements with connected devices and e.g. cut power if required. In contrast to this, a USB flash drive (aka "mass storage device") is a USB **device**, which does not provide a voltage on Vbus.

As far as I know, this contradiction makes it impossible to have both features combined in one device *per standard*.

Comment: Is this still true in the days of USB 3, USB PD and type C connectors?